# Creating and validating a tiered pricing form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am trying to create a tiered pricing form that would allow us to change the price depending on how much the customer is using.

I have created a form where we can add and remove tiers, but I want to be able to validate this, so the first option should always start with 0, there should be no max on the last tier, there should be no overlap, and there should be no gaps between the tiers.

For example:
0-5, 6-10, 11-15, 15-20, 21+

Instead of:
2-5, 7-11, 10-12, 13-19, 20+

```js
function update_max(){
  var pricing_tiers = document.getElementsByClassName("batch_pricing_tier");
  for(var i=0; i<pricing_tiers.length; i++){
    if(i!=0){
      var previous_tier = pricing_tiers.item(i-1);
      var previous_cols = previous_tier.children;
      var previous_max = parseInt(previous_cols[0].children[0].children[1].value);
    }else{
      var previous_max = -1;
    }
    var pricing_tier = pricing_tiers.item(i);
    var pricing_cols = pricing_tier.children;
    var minimum = parseInt(pricing_cols[0].children[0].children[1].value);
    var maximum = parseInt(pricing_cols[1].children[0].children[1].value);
    if(minimum <= previous_max){
      var new_min = previous_max+2;
      pricing_cols[0].children[0].children[1].value = new_min;
      minimum = new_min;
    }
    if(maximum <= minimum){
      var new_max = minimum+1;
      pricing_cols[1].children[0].children[1].value = new_max;
    }
  }
}
$(".batch_add").click(function(){
  $("#batch_form > div > div:first-child").clone(true).insertBefore("#batch_form > div > div:last-child");
  update_max();
});
$(".batch_remove").click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  update_max();
});
$(".max_update").change(function(){
  update_max();
});
$("#batch_pricing_submit").click(function(){
  var pricing_array = [];
  var pricing_tiers = document.getElementsByClassName("batch_pricing_tier");
  for(var i=0; i<pricing_tiers.length; i++){
    pricing_array[i] = {};
    var pricing_tier = pricing_tiers.item(i);
    var pricing_cols = pricing_tier.children;
    var minimum = pricing_cols[0].children[0].children[1].value;
    var maximum = pricing_cols[1].children[0].children[1].value;
    var price = pricing_cols[2].children[0].children[1].value;
    pricing_array[i]['minimum'] = minimum;
    pricing_array[i]['maximum'] = maximum;
    pricing_array[i]['price'] = price;
  }
  console.log(pricing_array);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="form m-3" id="batch_form" method="POST">
  <div>
    <div class="row batch_pricing_tier">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="minimum">Minimum</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" value="0" required disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="maximum">Maximum</label>
          <input class="form-control max_update" type="text" value="1" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="price">Price</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Price" name="price" id="price" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <br /><span class="batch_remove float-right">Remove</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row batch_pricing_tier">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="minimum">Minimum</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" value="2" required disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="maximum">Maximum</label>
          <input class="form-control max_update" type="text" value="inf" required disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="price">Price</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Price" name="price" id="price" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <br /><span class="batch_remove float-right">Remove</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="d-block w-100 align-center">
    <span class="batch_add float-right">Add fields</span>
    <br />
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="batch_pricing_submit" onclick="return false;">Add Batch Pricing</button>
  </span>
</form>
```

### Edit

This is for a usage based pricing model. So the price should get cheaper the more a customer uses. For example:

```
$10/unit for 0 to 5 units.
$9/unit for 6 to 10 units.
$8/unit for 11 to 15 units.
```

So if a user uses 8 units in a billing period they would be charged $9 x 8 units which would total $72.

Each product is different so will have different tiers of different unit amounts so I need to validate this.
I need the first tier minimum to start at 0.
The maximum of any tier should be larger than the minimum.
The minimum of the next tier should be larger than the maximum of the previous.
There should be no gaps between tiers.
There should be no overlap between tiers.

Comment: it is still not clear what are you expecting. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Write an input example and an expected output for the fields, and explain how can we use your form. As is, it's very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write the update_max function in a way so it would update the fields so it would be as you wish.

```js
function update_max() {
  let previous_max = -1;
  let previous_min = 0;

  $(".batch_pricing_tier").each(function(i, el) {
    const minimumInput = $(el).find(".min_update")[0];
    const maximumInput = $(el).find(".max_update")[0];
    let minimum = previous_max + 1;
    let maximum = Math.max(Number(maximumInput.value), minimum + 1);

    previous_min = minimumInput.value = minimum;
    if (!maximumInput.classList.contains("last_max"))
      previous_max = maximumInput.value = maximum;
  });

}

$(".batch_add").click(function() {
  $("#batch_form > div > div:first-child").clone(true).insertBefore("#batch_form > div > div:last-child");
  update_max();
});

$(".batch_remove").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  update_max();
});

$(".max_update").change(update_max);

$("#batch_pricing_submit").click(function() {
  var pricing_array = [];

  $(".batch_pricing_tier").each(function(i, el) {
    const minimumInput = $(el).find(".min_update")[0];
    const maximumInput = $(el).find(".max_update")[0];
    const priceInput = $(el).find(".price")[0];

    pricing_array.push({
      maximum: Number(minimumInput.value),
      minimum: Number(maximumInput.value),
      price: Number(priceInput.value),
    });
  });
  console.log(pricing_array);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="form m-3" id="batch_form" method="POST">
  <div>
    <div class="row batch_pricing_tier">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Minimum
                    <input class="form-control min_update" type="number" value="0" required disabled>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Maximum
                    <input class="form-control max_update" type="number" value="1" required>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Price
                    <input class="form-control price" type="text" placeholder="Price" name="price" id="price" required>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <br /><span class="batch_remove float-right">Remove</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row batch_pricing_tier">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Minimum
                    <input class="form-control min_update" type="number" value="2" required disabled>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Maximum
                    <input class="form-control max_update last_max" type="text" value="inf" required disabled>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Price
                    <input class="form-control price" type="text" placeholder="Price" name="price" id="price" required>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <br /><span class="batch_remove float-right">Remove</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="d-block w-100 align-center">
          <span class="batch_add float-right">Add fields</span>
  <br />
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="batch_pricing_submit" onclick="return false;">Add Batch Pricing</button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two validation conditions (start with 0 and end with inf) which are at known positions. All the others (e.g. no gaps and no overlaps) are about comparing each tier to the next tier. So you loop through them, from the beginning to the penultimate tier, comparing the `i`th tier to the `i + 1`th tier. This allows you to check through these conditions and find out exactly what is incorrect and where. If no issues are found, then it's valid.

```js
function update_max() {
  var pricing_tiers = document.getElementsByClassName("batch_pricing_tier");
  for (var i = 0; i < pricing_tiers.length; i++) {
    if (i != 0) {
      var previous_tier = pricing_tiers.item(i - 1);
      var previous_cols = previous_tier.children;
      var previous_max = parseInt(previous_cols[0].children[0].children[1].value);
    } else {
      var previous_max = -1;
    }
    var pricing_tier = pricing_tiers.item(i);
    var pricing_cols = pricing_tier.children;
    var minimum = parseInt(pricing_cols[0].children[0].children[1].value);
    var maximum = parseInt(pricing_cols[1].children[0].children[1].value);
    if (minimum <= previous_max) {
      var new_min = previous_max + 2;
      pricing_cols[0].children[0].children[1].value = new_min;
      minimum = new_min;
    }
    if (maximum <= minimum) {
      var new_max = minimum + 1;
      pricing_cols[1].children[0].children[1].value = new_max;
    }
  }
}
$(".batch_add").click(function() {
  $("#batch_form > div > div:first-child").clone(true).insertBefore("#batch_form > div > div:last-child");
  update_max();
});
$(".batch_remove").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  update_max();
});
$(".max_update").change(function() {
  update_max();
});
$("#batch_pricing_submit").click(function() {
  var pricing_array = [];
  var pricing_tiers = document.getElementsByClassName("batch_pricing_tier");
  for (var i = 0; i < pricing_tiers.length; i++) {
    pricing_array[i] = {};
    var pricing_tier = pricing_tiers.item(i);
    var pricing_cols = pricing_tier.children;
    var minimum = pricing_cols[0].children[0].children[1].value;
    var maximum = pricing_cols[1].children[0].children[1].value;
    var price = pricing_cols[2].children[0].children[1].value;

    pricing_array[i]['minimum'] = minimum;
    pricing_array[i]['maximum'] = maximum;
    pricing_array[i]['price'] = price;
  }
  console.log(pricing_array);

  console.log(validate(pricing_array));
});

function validate(pricing_array) {
  var i = 0;
  var min = null;
  var max = null;
  var price = null;
  var nextMin = null;
  var nextPrice = null;

  //Does the first option start with 0?
  if (parseInt(pricing_array[0].minimum) !== 0) {
    return "First option does not start with 0";
  };

  //No max on last tier
  if (typeof getInt(pricing_array[pricing_array.length - 1].maximum) === "number") {
    return "The last tier must not have a maximum";
  };

  if (0 < pricing_array.length) {
    for (i = 0; i < pricing_array.length - 1; i++) {
      //Check data types
      min = getInt(pricing_array[i].minimum);
      max = getInt(pricing_array[i].maximum);
      price = getInt(pricing_array[i].price);
      nextMin = getInt(pricing_array[i + 1].minimum);
      nextPrice = getInt(pricing_array[i + 1].price);

      if (typeof max !== "number") {
        return "The Maximum entered on Tier " + (i + 1) + " is not a number.";
      };

      if (typeof price !== "number") {
        return "The Price entered on Tier " + (i + 1) + " is not a number.";
      };

      if (typeof nextMin !== "number") {
        return "The Minimum entered on Tier " + (i + 2) + " is not a number.";
      };

      if (typeof nextPrice !== "number") {
        return "The Price entered on Tier " + (i + 2) + " is not a number.";
      };

      //Check max and min
      if (max < min) {
        return "The Maximum on Tier " + (i + 1) + " is less than the Minimum.";
      };

      //Check no overlap - must be larger
      if (nextMin <= max) {
        return "Tier " + (i + 1) + " overlaps with Tier " + (i + 2) + ".";
      };

      //Check no gaps
      if (1 < (nextMin - max)) {
        return "There is a gap between Tier " + (i + 1) + " and Tier " + (i + 2) + ".";
      };

      //Does the price get cheaper?
      if (nextPrice <= price) {
        return "The Price does not get cheaper between Tier " + (i + 1) + " and Tier " + (i + 2) + ".";
      };
    };
  };

  return "OK";
};

function getInt(val) {
  return parseInt(val) || val;
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="form m-3" id="batch_form" method="POST">
  <div>
    <div class="row batch_pricing_tier">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="minimum">Minimum</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" value="0" required disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="maximum">Maximum</label>
          <input class="form-control max_update" type="text" value="1" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="price">Price</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Price" name="price" id="price" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <br /><span class="batch_remove float-right">Remove</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row batch_pricing_tier">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="minimum">Minimum</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" value="2" required disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="maximum">Maximum</label>
          <input class="form-control max_update" type="text" value="inf" required disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="price">Price</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Price" name="price" id="price" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <br /><span class="batch_remove float-right">Remove</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="d-block w-100 align-center">
    <span class="batch_add float-right">Add fields</span>
  <br />
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="batch_pricing_submit" onclick="return false;">Add Batch Pricing</button>
  </span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following snippet. There are some changes from your original code, but in general something like this is what is needed.

```js
function update_max(index,quantity=1) {
  if (index >= 0) {
    let val = (index == 0 ? 0 : $(document).find('.row.batch_pricing_tier[data-row="' + index + '"] input.max_update').val());
    $.each($(document).find('.row.batch_pricing_tier'), (k, x) => {
      let row = parseInt($(x).attr('data-row'));
      if (row > index) {
        let items = $(x).find('input.form-control:not(.price)');
        $.each(items, (i, y) => {
          if ($(y).hasClass('max_update')) {
            $(y).val(parseInt($(items[i - 1]).val()) + quantity);
          } else {
            if (index == 0 && row == 1) {
              $(y).val(index);
            } else {
              $(y).val(parseInt($(document).find('.row.batch_pricing_tier[data-row="' + (row - 1 < index ? index : row - 1) + '"] input.max_update').val()) + 1);
            }
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
$(".batch_add").click(function() {
  let clone = $("#batch_form > div > div:first-child").clone(true);
  $("#batch_form > div").append(clone);
  let tiers = $(document).find('.row.batch_pricing_tier');
  $("#batch_form > div > div:last-child").attr('data-row', tiers.length)
  //update_max(tiers.length - 1); // default quantity 1
  update_max(tiers.length - 1,4);
});
$(".batch_remove").click(function() {
  let tiers = $(document).find('.row.batch_pricing_tier');

  if (tiers.length > 1) {
    let index = $(this).parents('.row.batch_pricing_tier').attr('data-row');
    $(this).parents('.row.batch_pricing_tier').remove();
    $.each($(document).find('.row.batch_pricing_tier'), (k, x) => {
      $(x).attr('data-row', k + 1);
    });
    //update_max(index - 1); // default quantity 1
    update_max(index - 1,4);
  }
});
$(document).on("change", ".max_update", function() {
  let index = $(this).parents('.row.batch_pricing_tier').attr('data-row');
  //update_max(index); // default quantity 1
  update_max(index,4);
});
$("#batch_pricing_submit").click(function() {
  var pricing_array = [];
  var pricing_tiers = document.getElementsByClassName("batch_pricing_tier");
  for (var i = 0; i < pricing_tiers.length; i++) {
    pricing_array[i] = {};
    var pricing_tier = pricing_tiers.item(i);
    var pricing_cols = pricing_tier.children;
    var minimum = pricing_cols[0].children[0].children[1].value;
    var maximum = pricing_cols[1].children[0].children[1].value;
    var price = pricing_cols[2].children[0].children[1].value;
    pricing_array[i]['minimum'] = minimum;
    pricing_array[i]['maximum'] = maximum;
    pricing_array[i]['price'] = price;
  }
  console.log(pricing_array);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form class="form m-3" id="batch_form" method="POST">
  <div>
    <div class="row batch_pricing_tier" data-row="1">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="minimum">Minimum</label>
          <input class="form-control" type="text" pattern="[0-9]" value="0" required disabled>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="maximum">Maximum</label>
          <input class="form-control max_update" pattern="[0-9]" type="text" value="5" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="price">Price</label>
          <input class="form-control price" type="text" placeholder="Price" name="price" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <br /><span class="batch_remove float-right">Remove</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="d-block w-100 align-center">
    <span class="batch_add float-right">Add fields</span>
  <br />
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" id="batch_pricing_submit" onclick="return false;">Add Batch Pricing</button>
  </span>
</form>
```